# Spring MVC returning 406 to controller test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I have the following project tree:

```
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── child
│       │   │       └── app
│       │   │           └── Application.java
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── application-default.yaml
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── child
│                   └── app
│                       └── ApplicationTest.java
├── build.gradle
└── childA
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   └── java
        │       └── child
        │           └── a
        │               ├── CoreConfig.java
        │               ├── PingController.java
        │               └── SpringWebMvcInitializer.java
        └── test
            └── java
            │   └── child
            │       └── a
            │           └── PingControllerTest.java
            └── resources
                └── application-core.yml
```

I have the following test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PingController.class, SpringWebMvcInitializer.class }, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({ "core" })
public class PingControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPing() throws Exception {
this.mockMvc.perform(get(CoreHttpPathStore.PING)).andDo(print());
this.mockMvc.perform(get(CoreHttpPathStore.PING).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I have the following `PingController.java`:

```
@RestController
public class PingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = CoreHttpPathStore.PING, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> ping() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", "Welcome to our API");
        map.put("date", new Date());
        map.put("status", HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I have the following `SpringWebMvcInitializer.java`:

```
@ComponentScan
public class SpringWebMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }

}
```

### Expected

I expect test to pass with http code `200`.

### Result

I get `406` and the following `print()`:

```
04:29:47.488 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /ping
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.kopaxgroup.api.core.controller.PingController

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 406
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

### Question

So here are my questions :

- I have done some googling and most of the answers says that the context needs to be loaded with `@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")`, I use JAVA configuration and I have no XML. Is my `SpringWebMvcInitializer.java` replacing that file and is it replacing it correctly ?
- Why do I get 406 error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easy way is to create `TestApplication` class and put it in `/childA/test/java/a`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
}
```

and I think it is better to use the following annotation for tests if you use Spring Boot:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"core"})
public class PingControllerTest {
...
}
```

Comment: I have many sub project `childB`, `childC` ... so what is the goal of moving `TestApplication` ?

Comment: I mean to create a new class TestApplication for every sub-project and put it on the level of the sub-project (/childA/test/java/a/TestAplication.java, /childB/test/java/b/TestAplication.java). This class should have only the annotation @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: I have tried and this will return a 404 error code. It seems the `@SpringBootApplication` needs to beimported somehow in the test ? I have tried to import it using `@ContextConfiguration` and it also started to whine because of dataSource not being configured correctly. I have tried to annotate the `TestApplication` with `@ComponentScan("my.package")` and it didnt improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a content type.
    `this.mockMvc.perform(get(CoreHttpPathStore.PING).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))andExpect(status().isOk());`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with your example and it does also return `406`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below steps:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public static class PingControllerTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public PingController myController() {
            return new PingController();
        }
    }
```

and

changing below

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PingController.class, SpringWebMvcInitializer.class }, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

to `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: Is this a test for debugging purpose ? Where would I create that new file and why would I do that for each of my controllers?

Comment: This you will be doing in your PingControllerTest class, PingControllerTestConfiguration  class is an inner class in your PingControllerTest class to intantiate the controller for testing

Comment: This work but why do I need to do write this ? It is not what the documentatione describe. Also, will this also work with securized controllers and `spring-security` and `spring-security-oauth` ? What about if I need to have my configuration loaded (for example if a controller is `@Auowiring` `MailService` ?

Comment: I haven't tried this with spring security, you can try and test it. EnableWebMvc annotation enables support for `@Controller`-annotated classes that use `@RequestMapping` to map incoming requests to a certain method. In Test class it is working is same way as any AppConfig class for Java annotation spring context.

Comment: I have tried and it does not work in most of my cases. I need to be able to autowire within controllers. This work for most simple cases.

Comment: what is not working in most of your cases, above solution of creating inner class to declare controller bean?

Comment: This work FINE. In a real worl, your application will use a bunch of services, initializing a bean and skipping the context configuration is generaly not possible.